# Adjust graphs inside GraphicsRow to be the same scale?

Tags: plotting

I want to draw a picture with `GraphicsRow` function in Mathematica. A simple example shows as follows

```
data1 = RandomInteger[5, {16, 16}];
data2 = RandomInteger[1000000000, {16, 16}];
fig1 = MatrixPlot[data1, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0, 0.5}], 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
   ImageSize -> 400];
fig2 = MatrixPlot[data2, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {1, 0.5}], 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, Automatic}, {Automatic, None}}, 
   ImageSize -> 400];
GraphicsRow[{fig1, fig2}, Spacings -> -2]
```

The execution result is
[image]
where the two graphs are not of the same size. I then add `AspectRatio -> Full`  action inside `MatrixPlot`. The result becomes [image]
But now the two graphs have different widths. I think the size of the two graphs does not agree because their legends are different. Since when I remove the `PlotLegend` option, the result becomes [image]

So how can I let the two pictures agree in size while keeping the legends?

My `$Version` result is `13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)`.

Comment: These functionalities have been improved on the latest versions of Mathematica. What is your version ?

Comment: @andre314 My `$Version` result is `13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)`. Do you mean if I install version 13.2 the problem will be fixed?

Comment: I have tested on Mma 13.2. It turns out that there are no improvements for this specific problem (more precisely `PlotMatrix` does not have the option `"PlotLayout"` )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the following do the job :

```
(* this is exactly your code : *)
data1 = RandomInteger[5, {16, 16}];
data2 = RandomInteger[1000000000, {16, 16}];
fig1 = MatrixPlot[data1, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0, 0.5}], 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
   ImageSize -> 400];
fig2 = MatrixPlot[data2, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {1, 0.5}], 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, Automatic}, {Automatic, None}}, 
   ImageSize -> 400];   

(* then the new thing : *)

Legended[GraphicsRow[{fig1[[1]], fig2[[1]]}], {Placed[fig1[[2, 1]], 
   Before], Placed[fig2[[2, 1]], After]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you want more control over how exactly your plots are laid out, you can use [`ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid/):

```
data1 = RandomInteger[5, {16, 16}];
data2 = RandomInteger[1000000000, {16, 16}];
fig1 = MatrixPlot[data1, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Left]];
fig2 = MatrixPlot[data2, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Right]];

ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{{fig1, fig2}}]
```

[image]

Note how there is no need to remove the frame/image size manually, and how the default setting for `Spacings` is effectively gluing the plots together, without any "magic" numbers. Please note that I had to change the legend positioning to `Left`/`Right` to achieve the optimal results, the original settings were not behaving as nicely. (settings such as `{-0.05, 0.5}`/`{1.05, 0.5}` also work, but you'll have to play around with the numbers to make it look like you want)

Answer (score 0):

The trick seems to be to transfer the size as a variable to the internal code of execution

```
    data1 = RandomInteger[5, {16, 16}];
   data2 = RandomInteger[1000000000, {16, 16}];

fig1 := MatrixPlot[data1, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Scaled[{0, 0.5}]], 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
   ImageSize -> Medium ] ;

fig2[s_] := 
  MatrixPlot[data2, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Scaled[{1, 0.5}]], 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, Automatic}, {Automatic, None}} ,ImageSize -> {s, s}];

 GraphicsRow[{fig1, fig2[420]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But it seems the left graph has lower height than the right one..

Comment: Perhaps fine tunig of the first guess 420-size will help. Of course its possible to define  both images as functions of its own sizes  and try a Manipulate[  ]  in order to exactly find the right parameters.